# Upgrading ImageMagick on Heroku

Tags: heroku, imagemagick

Is this possible? If so how I do upgrade from Version XXX to Version XXXX?

I can't seem to find any docs on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Heroku maintain imagemagick as part of the service so you'd have to convince them to upgrade it across the platform.

Comment: I know you can include your own files in `/bin`, maybe there is a way around it here?

Comment: Just contacted customer support, they said the same thing. But they said you can include files in `/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

The way to upgrade ImageMagick on heroku now is by using a 'buildpack'.

If you search through the buildpacks on heroku: https://elements.heroku.com/search/buildpacks?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=imagemagick you can see there are quite a few dedicated to updating ImageMagick.

You can install a custom buildpack by using the following command line call:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-erlang
  Buildpack set. Next release on random-app-1234 will use https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-erlang.
  Run `git push heroku master` to create a new release using this buildpack.
```

More information about buildpacks can be found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks